# Inside a class extends thread. Where to put another class creation?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two classes, 
Class_A is to accept packets. (with multi-threads)
Class_B is to parse each time packets received.
What I want to do is to let Class_A create new thread when there is new coming packet.
and each Class_A thread will create Class_B instance to parse the packets.

```
    public class Class_A extends Thread{

      public Class_A(){

      }

      public void run() {
        Class_B B=new ClassB();
        B.xxxxxxx;
      }
    }
```

I wonder if there is a any difference or better to create B instance in the constructor? 
Or at the beginning of Class_A?

Thank you

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to achieve. `B` in your sample is a local variable; If you want to initialize in constructor, you will have to make it a member of `Class_A`.

Comment: Does `B` have to be a class that maintains state or can it be a helper class ? Submit each `A` to a threadpool. If `B` requires state create an instance and make it a member of `A` for each invocation. Else just call `B.myAwesomeMethod(packet)` from `run()`.

Comment: B has some attributes and after called by Class_A, those attributes would be updated. Can you also explain what is the meaning of "Submit each A to a threadpool"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If ClassB is always going to be used for the same purpose and no modification in its attributes, make it an attribute of A and put its initialization on the Constructor of ClassA to avoid instantiating classes without need (loss of memory and performance). Remember that every new instance of a class that won't be used anymore is more garbage for the GC to collect.

Also, don't use

```
extends Thread
```

A better practice, instead, is to use

```
implements Runnable
```

So that you'll have more freedom in your hierarchy (I recommend reading Effective Java for quick tips like this one).